# I don't understand what this error means

Tags: python-3.x

I am brand new to programming. I have researched this error message and I am not sure what it means or how to solve the problem; does anyone have any insight for this error.

```
    firstName=input('Enter your first name: ')
    middleName=input('Enter your middle name: ')
    lastName=input(firstName,middleName'enter your last name: ')

    >>> 
    Enter your first name: Steve
    Enter your middle name: Smith
    >>>Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\rps.py", line 3, in <module>
    lastName=input(firstName,middleName,'Enter your last name: ')
    TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
    >>>
```

Comment: In general, when posting to StackOverflow please cut and paste *exactly* the code you ran, without edits.  Your first "lastName" line has no comma after middleName and has a lowercase "enter", whereas the one in the error message has a comma after middleName and a capital "E" in enter.  So the code at the top isn't the code that was in rps.py.  Here it was easy to see what was going on, but sometimes subtler differences like this can lead to lots of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
lastName=input(firstName,middleName'enter your last name: ')
```

The error refers to the line above. It says that 'input', the function, expects a single argument, but you've given three. I expect your last line should probably be:

```
lastName=input('Enter your last name: ')
```

Comment: Ah, Thank you; that makes sense. What is the proper syntax for instructing the program to print the firstName and the middleName in the input "Enter your last name: "?

Comment: You really need to look at a tutorial. The internet is full of resources and python is extremely well documented. I don't think that continuing to answer questions will help you at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I do not mean to insult your intelligence or anything. But if you're brand new to programming, I would really consider a course, book, and/or inspecting existing code examples like 'hello world' and so on carefully.

Due to the fact you did not post your actual code of 'rps.py', we can't know exactly what's going wrong.

But I'm quite sure that you have a function called 'input', which accepts a string.
As 'last name', you try to call the 'input' method with 3 arguments. the 'firsname', 'middlename', and the 'enter your lastname' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To create a string parameter from string variables and a string literal, you would concatenate them to one string, which then is a correct parameter for the input(str) function. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html.